# C# debugging a target process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I wish to build a small debugger in C# that allows me to attach to another c# project and debug it.
I believe Microsoft has a dll that allows me to do this.

For example if I know the code in the target process then I can look for certain Classes and interrogate them etc and look at their member variables etc.

What is this Microsoft dll called??

Comment: Why dont you use the build in Debugger attach to process?

Comment: I disagree with the close vote: IMHO this question is not a recommendation issue for a tool or library, OP is looking for the one and only Microsoft DLL.

Answer (score 1):

It is called the [debugger engine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and resides in `dbgeng.dll`. However, this is not a managed DLL.

For .NET, there is also [MDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19621), but it doesn't have as many features.

Also note: you can get information about objects and member variables, but it may fail to get local variables on the stack in Release mode if the code was optimized.

If you want to do similar things, e.g. to get familiar with the possibilities, you can try Microsoft's Debugger [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) and the .NET extension [sos](/questions/tagged/sos).

First commands to get started with WinDbg and SOS:

```
.loadby sos clr
!dumpheap -stat
```